# Multibib not working with TeXworks but works in Overleaf

Tags: overleaf, texworks, multibib

I've been trying for days to get multibib to work with TeXWorks and I honestly can't figure out what I'm doing wrong - I think there's some additional compiling that I'm supposed to be doing but I'm having trouble figuring out what those additional steps are.  I am trying to create a document with a bibliography for "references" and a bibliography for "enclosures."  My bibliography file is titled "bibtest.bib."

```
    \documentclass{report}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \graphicspath{ {images/}}
    \usepackage{parskip}
    \usepackage{multibib}
    %Secondary bibliography
    \newcites{ref}{References}
    \newcites{enc}{Enclosures}


     \title{MultipleBibsTest}
     \author{AS }


     \begin{document}
     \maketitle

     Front matter.....\par

     \bibliographystyleenc{alpha}
     \bibliographyenc{bibtest}
     \bibliographystyleref{ieeetr}
     \bibliographyref{bibtest}
     \newpage

     Text with \citeref{einstein} and \citeenc{dirac}.

     \end{document}
```

This compiles fine in Overleaf, but I get nothing with TeXWorks.  I'm not sure what to do with the .aux files.  I've tried creating a batch file as directed in [this example](https://9to5science.com/multibib-with-texworks-how-to-parse-second-aux-file) with no luck.  I click on the batch file to process the .aux files and then try compiling the code over again and still get the same result.  Any guidance is greatly appreciated.  If it matters, I'm using TeXmaker 4.5.  I've already tried to compile in the following order: PDFLaTeX -> BibTeX -> PDFLaTeX and it doesn't recognize the additional bibliographies or the commands introduced with \newcites.  I'm using Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Following up with this:

Turns out I didn't have the appropriate .bbl files for TeXWorks to make into the bibliography.  It generated two .aux files (enc.aux and ref.aux).  I had to open both these files with TeXWorks and manually compile with BibTeX to generate enc.bbl and ref.bbl.  After doing this, I went back into my main program and compiled with the combo PDFLaTeX -> BibTeX -> PDFLaTeX and it worked.

This [thread](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2011) is what gave me the tip, in addition to reading the .log file of my main program.